Add Javascript REST call to Spring Boot Security for MVC/Thymeleaf page
I have a Spring Boot/MVC/Thymeleaf web application I am working on. Authentication and Authorization are working great!
However, I would like to have an <input...> that calls a REST endpoint to perform real-time DB lookups to see if an email entered already exists.
I would like to somehow use the same session the user has for the web page they are on so that the REST endpoint will only work for people who have authenticated with they system (so random folk can't write a script to slam that endpoint).
I have researched (probably poorly!) and not found a solution, or if it is doable.
Thanks!
